# Troubleshooting why PHP works in IIS7 for one site, but not another?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

I have some basic PHP scripts that display pictures, etc.  Nothing fancy.

This is IIS7 running in Windows 2016.

I have several sites set up.  Followed the instructions here:
https://www.assistanz.com/steps-to-install-php-manually-on-windows-2016-server/

In the end, I create a PHP Info file, and create a website in IIS with the PHP file in the root directory.  It works fine.  However, when I try with any other site I have in IIS, it doesn't, and I can't open the file.

I narrowed it down to security.  Each site has its own user account, and that user account is the only thing that has access to the root directory.  IIS has the specific account (and password) entered in so each site only has access to its own site.

If I navigate to the root directory for the site and add read permission to 'Everyone', then it works just fine, and PHP files underneath it are read with no issues.

There's got to be something I'm missing here - I don't believe I need to allow 'users' or 'everyone' read access to every site.  IIS can load the site just fine and HTML, JPG, and other files render just fine with no access issues - it's just PHP that don't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds as if you have configured the handler mapping on the site level, instead of the server level. IIS allows for this, just so that you can have different websites each running a different PHP version. Go back to the page where you got the instructions from, and check the part that says *CONFIGURE PHP IN IIS*. Be sure you are on the top level (server level).

Comment: I confirmed that the handler mappings are set at the server level.  The handler mappings for each individual site match exactly what is at the server

Comment: I'm shooting blind here, but maybe those users need to be part of a group with permissions? I'm hoping this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887131/add-writing-permission-to-php-on-iis-7 If not, maybe there's an error message on the event log that might help...